# Is it possible to specify/automate data types when getting data from the web (in a CSV format) with Power BI?

Tags: csv, powerbi

Currently when getting the data, all fields are considered as a data type of text, however in reality, some of the fields are numbers and some are dates.

The workaround is to change the property type in Power BI after getting the data, but I have been asked if it's possible for this to be automated.

Currently the data is presented to Power BI as a CSV file, but we could change to a different format if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerBI has option to auto detect column types

[image]

In powerquery, you could also do Transform .. Detect Data Type